# Why don't you need to pass arguments to a qsort comparator function?

Tags: c, parameters, parameter-passing, void-pointers, qsort

Code below taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/).

```
* qsort example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<6; n++)
     printf ("%d ",values[n]);
  return 0;
}
```

We have a compare function with parameters in its signature but when we call it in qsort no arguments are passed.  How are the values of `a` and `b` passed to the function?  Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question, but your comparison function has a major bug unless you know a priori that the range of integers in your array is bounded by `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @R.. I just took it from cpluscplus.com, thanks though

Comment: Yet another reason why cplusplus.com is an atrociously bad source for C and C++ information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of this expression:

```
qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
```

the subexpression `compare` that identifies a function decays into a pointer to that function (and not a function call). The code is effectively equivalent to:

```
qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), &compare);
```

This is exactly the same thing that happens to arrays when used as arguments to a function (which you might or not have seen before but is more frequently asked):

```
void f( int * x );
int main() {
   int array[10];
   f( array );      // f( &array[0] )
}
```

Comment: So writing a function pointer without the ampersand just the lazy way of doing it?

Comment: In a function call, the compiler translates the function for a pointer to the function. The reason is that, just like arrays, a function cannot really be passed by value so the language has specific rules that will perform that conversion both in a function declaration and the call. `typedef void function(); void f( function f );` is translated into `typedef void function();` void f( function* f );` in the declaration, and `f( myvoidfunction )` is translated into `f( &myvoidfunction )` at the place of call.

Comment: I would not call it the lazy way; I would call it the consistent way. The `()` operator (i.e. the function call operator) takes a function pointer as its operand. Unless you go around writing `(&function)(...);` every time you make a function call, it's inconsistent to write `&function` when you want to use the address of a function for a non-call purpose.

Comment: @R.. I am not too sure about that. The standard clearly states that for a regular function call, the postfix expression shall be either a function or a function pointer, so `func()` is correct on the first account. On the other hand, only a function pointer can be passed as argument to another function. That is, the standard is quite clear that you can call a function, but you can only pass a pointer to a function. Whether you prefer one or the other syntax is a different issue, but if the goal is consistency then you should pass `&func`.

Comment: Where do you get that? C99 6.5.2.2 reads (under Constraints): "The expression that denotes the called function80) shall have type pointer to function returning void or returning an object type other than an array type." And footnote 80 reads: "Most often, this is the result of converting an identifier that is a function designator," i.e. if the expression is just a function name, it becomes a function pointer by decay.

Comment: By the way, relying on decay does not work for calling functions that were never declared, so perhaps pre-C99 versions that allowed implicit function declaration had extra language to account for that. Implicit declaration was removed in C99 so the decay semantics suffice to specify the desired behavior.

Comment: @R.. I got it from the C++ standard (I now see that the question has been retagged as C) I will look into the C standard to find whether the behavior is the same or not.

Comment: ... After a cursory read of the C11 standard it seems that in C function calls are also performed through function pointers always. The function identifier is processed as a function pointer in all contexts.

Comment: It's not a pointer following `sizeof`; `sizeof function` is not a valid way to get the size of a function pointer.

Answer (score 3):

When calling qsort, you're passing a pointer to the function which is why you don't specify any parameters.

Inside the qsort implementation choses values from the 'values' array and calls the 'compare' function.  That's how 'a' and 'b' get passed.

Answer (score 1):

`qsort` passes the addresses of whichever items in the array it wants to compare.  For example, `&values[3]` and `&values[5]`.

Since it doesn't really know the actual types of the items in the array, it uses the `size` parameter to correctly compute the addresses.  See this implementation for example: http://insanecoding.blogspot.ie/2007/03/quicksort.html